# How to use forked packages with dep golang?

Tags: go

How can I use my own forked package easily using dep?

I would love to be able to use the upstream again when my changes are accepted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While `dep` is no longer the prefered way of doing this, (go modules preferred as of go1.11)

With constraints this is easy, it will still be referenced everywhere in code and resolved via `github.com/upstream/repo`.

```
[[constraint]]
  name = "github.com/upstream/repo"
  branch = "forked-branch-name"
  source = "github.com/lexton/repo"
```